How to obtain the previous step/transaction by id in Power BI and total time spent in rejection status?
I have data in the format below where each transaction per ID is captured. I am trying to get a count of the transactions an ID was in prior to being rejected.
So for XYZ it would be:
Acknowledge Receipt - 1
Pending Approval - 1
And overall the counts would look like:
Acknowledge Receipt - 1
Pending Approval - 3
Approve Request - 1
I've tried adding a rank to offset the data but it's made complicated by ID's that have been rejected multiple times. Then adding on to that, I also wanted to see how long something sat in a rejection status prior to moving to the next step, or if it's still in rejection status. But I wanted to focus on one problem first. I'm a little stumped by how to solve this.


Can you please provide sample data in tabular format so that someone can copy them to the dataset for test?

Can you expand on this "I am trying to get a count of the transactions an ID was in prior to being rejected." as I'm not quite understanding what you are meaning. Acknowledge Receipt is 1 or -1? And why?

Create these 4 columns-
Column-1:
PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 

var this_row_id = 'Table'[ID]
var this_row_tran_type = 'Table'[TRANSACTION_TYPE]
var this_row_tran_date = 'Table'[TRANSACTION_DATE]

var prev_max_date_same_id =
CALCULATE(
    max('Table'[TRANSACTION_DATE]),
    FILTER(
        all('Table'),
        'Table'[ID] = this_row_id
            && 'Table'[TRANSACTION_DATE] < this_row_tran_date
    )
)

var prev_max_date_tran_type =
CALCULATE(
    max('Table'[TRANSACTION_TYPE]),
    FILTER(
        all('Table'),
        'Table'[ID] = this_row_id
            && 'Table'[TRANSACTION_DATE] = prev_max_date_same_id
    )
)

RETURN prev_max_date_tran_type

Column-2:
ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_RECEIPT_COUNT = 
IF(
    'Table'[TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Reject Request" 
        && 'Table'[PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Acknowledgement Receipt",
        1
)

Column-3:
PENDING_APPROVAL_COUNT = 
IF(
    'Table'[TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Reject Request" 
        && 'Table'[PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Pending Approval",
        1
)

Column-4:
APPROVE_REQUEST_COUNT = 
IF(
    'Table'[TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Reject Request" 
        && 'Table'[PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION_TYPE] = "Approve Request",
        1
)

Here is the output-


Thank you very much. This answers the question I was struggling with

Hi @BreadPitt, nice to see this worked for you. Can you please also give an upvote to the answer if it really helped :)
